# Picking 4 balls with replacement.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I'd like your help with the following exercise I found in a set of difficult -at least for me- exercises. There is a box that contains **10 White**, **20 Black** and **30 Red balls**, we choose **4 with replacement**.

a. What's the probability we chose **at least one White ball**?

b. What's the probability we chose a**t least one White ball taking into account we didn't choose any Red ones**?(conditional)

c. What's the probability **we didn't choose any Red balls, taking into account that we chose at least one White ball**?(conditional)

So, b. and c. have to do with a. 
For a. I thought I could find the probability that I didn't choose any white balls.

The possible outcomes are: $\binom{20}4+\binom{20}3\binom{30}1+\binom{20}2\binom{30}2+\binom{20}1\binom{30}3+\binom{30}4$

Our sample space is: $\binom{60}4$

I don't know if I'm thinking of it correctly but that's what I've came up with so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are choosing with replacement, so you should just think in terms of drawing with $\frac 16$ chance of getting white, $\frac 13$ black, $\frac 12$ red.  The combinations assume you are drawing without replacement.  You have $\frac 56$ chance not to get white on each draw, so the chance you don't get  a white one is ???

Answer (score 0):

> I thought I could find the probability that I didn't choose any white balls.

Yes, that is the correct approach.   However, you are overcomplicating your count for the size of the favoured event.   (Also, the selection is *with replacement*.)

a. You wish to find probability for the complement of selecting 4 from **50 non-white** balls when selecting any 4 from 60 balls *with replacement*.$$\mathsf P(W>0)~=~1-\left(50/60\right)^4$$
b. You wish to find the probability for the complement of selecting 4 from 20 black balls when selecting any 4 from 30 black-or-white balls.$$\mathsf P(W>0\mid R=0)~=~\underline{\qquad}$$
c. Use Bayes' Rule.  $$\mathsf P(R=0\mid W>0) ~=~ \dfrac{\mathsf P(W>0\mid R=0)\,\mathsf P(R=0)}{\mathsf P(W>0)}$$